# Get Facebook API access token

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, access-token, facebook-access-token

I'm currently working on a project where I need to fetch the latest posts from a specific Facebook group using the Graph API endpoint: [https://graph.facebook.com/{group-id}/feed?limit=5&access_token=EAACEdEos0...](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bgroup-id%7D/feed?limit=5&access_token=EAACEdEos0...).

I'm stuck at the part where I need to obtain a valid access token to authenticate my requests. Can anyone guide me on where and how to get this access token for my application?

Comment: on April 22, 2024 the access to groups will stop working. Despite from that the group admin needs to install your app, before you can access the group info. If your project is not finished soon, I suggest to go for another project ;) https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version19.0#groups-api